# When a menu dropdown is open, close the others - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm trying to make that - in the vertical menu that you can see in [this W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8X86VS6PT7T) (the original one is [that](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown)) - when a dropdown is open, the others are closed.
Presently - as you can see from the demo - more dropdowns can be opened simultaneously, but I want that **just one** can be showed alone, and when I click on another button, the dropdown closes himself.
(Sorry for my bad english, but I'm italien, hope you understand my problem).
Do you know how can do this?
Thanks

[Here you can see that currently more dropdowns can be opened, which I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzN3Z.png)

Comment: Share your code, which you have tried.

Comment: It's nothing serious, because I'm not so gud with Javascript...
I really don't know how to do it : - (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to reply to you for your question asked on Stack Overflow.

As far as I understand you want an accordion-type dropdowns on the side as a menu that opens and closes simultaneously.

I have created a working code for you. Hope it meets your requirement.

**Javascript:-**

```
var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-container');
    var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');
    for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
        accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
    }
    function toggleItem() {

        var itemClass = this.nextElementSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
            accItem[i].style.display = "none";
            accHD[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        if (itemClass.style.display === "none") {
            this.classList.add("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        }

    }
```

**Working Fiddle:-** https://jsfiddle.net/fve7x8pr/1/

Thanks

Comment: Top, your answer is perfect for my problem... I'll give you +1 when I will have 15 reputation ;-) ---- Thank you bro

Comment: Thanks @Urel, nice to help you out.

Comment: Are you also able to do that, when i click on the open-close-button of a dropdown that is open, the dropdown close itself, like the W3schools example? (I hope you understand me)

Comment: Its the submenus of the dropdown which is closing, dropdown button is only showing active, inactive states...

Comment: Mhh ok, but is there any way to make that, like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8X86VS6PT7T), when I click on the dropdown button and the dropdown is open, the same dropdown closes himself?

Comment: I hope you understand my question...if not, tell me where is the problem

Comment: I understand your question, I will try to implement it, will let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought there was a problem in my question ;-)

Comment: No idea? ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎